# Azure Key Vault Access Error - AADSTS700027: Client assertion contains an invalid signature. [Reason - T (truncated...) while accessing via PHP

Tags: php, azure, rest, azure-keyvault

I am trying to integrate Azure Key Vault within my PHP application by making use of below sample.

https://github.com/bentaylorwork/php-azure-key-vault

and using https://tsmatz.wordpress.com/2017/03/03/azure-rest-api-with-certificate-and-service-principal-by-silent-backend-daemon-service/ as ref.

Using the approach which is mentioned in the article and GIT library, I am able to get my secrets from Azure Key Vault. However challenge here is that the said approach makes use of Client Secret rather then Certificate for Authentication (which is my preferred approach).

I have done same changes to the said library and are sending below request for authentication:

```
public static function getKeyVaultToken(array $azureAppDetails)
{
    $guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

    $token = $guzzle->post(
        "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{$azureAppDetails['appTenantDomainName']}/oauth2/token",
        [
            'form_params' => [
                'client_id'     => $azureAppDetails['clientId'],
                'client_assertion_type' => 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer',
                'resource'      => 'https://management.azure.com/',
                'grant_type'    => 'client_credentials',
        'client_assertion' => '', // This contains JWT token consisting with header, payload and digital signature using key.
            ]
        ]
    )->getBody()->getContents();

    return json_decode($token, true)['access_token'];
}
```

Here header, payload is as below:

```
$header = json_encode(['x5t' => 'thumbprint of certificate uploaded on Aazure', 'alg' => 'RS256', 'typ' => 'JWT']);

$payload = json_encode(['aud' => "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$azureAppDetails['appTenantDomainName']/oauth2/token", "exp" => 1609372800, "iss" => "ClientID", "jti" => "77b2b25f-0288-471f-8b44-3f3c134c0d4f","nbf" => 1603929600,"sub" => "ClientID" ]);
```

**Client Assertion here is combination of :**

```
base64uriencode($header).base64uriencode($payload).base65uriencode(digitalsignature)
```

When I send the above request with said parameters I am getting below error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException' with message 'Client error: `POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS700027: Client assertion contains an invalid signature. [Reason - T (truncated...)
```

Any help or guidance on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a service principal, you can send the principal ID and secret like in the following example, which is what we do in the Azure Key Vault SDK for .NET and other languages. You are also sending the wrong resource:

```
grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={{clientId}}&client_secret={{clientSecret}}&resource=https://vault.azure.net
```

This will give you a JSON payload back with the `access_token` you can pass in your `Authorization` header as the bearer token.

Comment: Thanks @Heath, however in my approach I am trying to avoid sending client secret via payload. I am seeing a way where I can use certificate instead of Secret..